# Count the amount of files in many folders and count number of characters in the names of the files in the folders

Tags: linux, terminal

I have one Linux question that I can't solve. I tried to solve it - I also tried to search the forum, but found no clue - or a way to solve it.

**Question:**

Write commands that count the amount of files in the Vegetables and Fruits folders together. The answer must be saved in a CounterFood file. Several commands are allowed.

After you execute these commands you are prompted to do so:

The total number of characters in the names of the files in the Vegetables and Fruits folders must be added to the CounterFood file. Several commands may be used.

**Try**

I thought about doing an arithmetic insert - but I didn't find such a command.

```
ls -l . Vegetables Fruits  | egrep -c '^-' >> CounterFood
```

I tried to count how many files there were - but I couldn't count the two folders together. Then I came up with this - my idea is to access the folders - and find all the files - and then count them

```
find Vegetables Fruits -type f | wc - >>CounterFood
```

The continuation of the question is directly related to the beginning. But the beginning didn't work out for me - I can't understand why.

Comment: Look at the `find` and `wc` commands (for both parts)

Comment: find Vegetables Fruits -type f | wc - >>CounterFood
I tried it:
My idea is to access the folders - and find all the files - and then count them

Comment: `man wc` and check the flags to control what it outputs

Answer (score 0):

**Total Number files in both folders :**

```
expr `ls -l Vegetables | sed 1d | wc -l` + `ls -l Fruits | sed 1d | wc -l` >> CounterFood
```

**Total Number of characters of filenames in both folders :**

```
expr `ls Vegetables | wc -c` + `ls Fruits  | wc -c` >> CounterFoods
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Part 1

```
find Vegetables Fruits -type f -printf "x" | wc -c > CounterFood      # Print "x" for each filename and count them
```

Part 2

If you meant *add* them then this will work

```
namelen=$(find Vegetables Fruits -type f -printf "%f" | wc -c)        # Characters in file names
counterfood=$(cat CounterFood)                                        # Previous total

echo $((namelen + counterfood)) > CounterFood                         # Add them together
```

If you meant *append* them then this will work

```
find Vegetables Fruits -type f -printf "%f" | wc -c >> CounterFood    # Characters in file names
```